# How can I control visibility of dynamically generated controls via context menu?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dynamic, mvvm

I have an ItemsControl that binds to a list of properties in my ViewModel, and using a DataTemplate, automatically generates the appropriate control depending on the type of the property.

Here is the code for the ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Properties}" >
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="StringTemplate" DataType="{x:Type ui:ControlStringData}" >
            <xctk:WatermarkTextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        Watermark="{Binding Path=Caption, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        Margin="5,5,5,5" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DateTimeTemplate" DataType="{x:Type ui:ControlDateTimeData}">
            <xctk:DateTimePicker Value="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        Watermark="{Binding Path=Caption, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        Margin="5,5,5,5" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultTemplate" />
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl
                    x:Name="MyContentControl"
                    Content="{Binding}"
                    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}"/>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Type}" Value="DateTime">
                    <Setter TargetName="MyContentControl" Property="ContentTemplate"
                                Value="{StaticResource DateTimeTemplate}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Type}" Value="String">
                    <Setter TargetName="MyContentControl" Property="ContentTemplate"
                                Value="{StaticResource StringTemplate}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Now given the generated control, I would like to create a ContextMenu that is populated with the Caption property and a checkbox, where each item in the ContextMenu is bound to the visibility of the corresponding control.

The current code I have is a button that will open a context menu like so:

```
<Button Margin="5,5,5,5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="16" Width="16">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContextMenu.IsOpen">
                                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True"/>
                                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu />

                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

How can I create the context menu and have the options be bounded to the visibility? I am stuck as I am unsure how to setup the bindings correctly to do this.

More details:

So in the above ItemsControl, it binds to a list of properties called 'Properties' where each element implements:

```
public interface IControlData
{
    string Type { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Caption { get; set; }
    bool Visibility { get; set; }
}
```

Based on the Type string, I use Data Triggers in the above to generate the correct control for that Type and they are placed in the ItemsControl which is templated to be a UniformGrid.

Now I would like to have a button that when clicked presents a list of the Names of each control in the ItemsControl and each entry is checkable, where the checkable state corresponds to the visibility of the control in the ItemsControl.

Example: If the ItemsControl grid is as such:

```
+----------+----------+
| TextBox1 | TextBox2 |
+----------+----------+
| TextBox3 | TextBox4 |
+----------+----------+
```

Then the context menu shown when I click the button would be:

```
+---+----------+
| ✓ | TextBox1 |
| ✓ | TextBox2 |
| ✓ | TextBox3 |
| ✓ | TextBox4 |
+---+----------+
```

If I click one of the entries in the ContextMenu, say for instance TextBox4, it would set the visibility of TextBox4 to false and the items control would look like:

```
+----------+----------+
| TextBox1 | TextBox2 |
+----------+----------+
| TextBox3 |          |
+----------+----------+
```

And the context menu would appear as:

```
+---+----------+
| ✓ | TextBox1 |
| ✓ | TextBox2 |
| ✓ | TextBox3 |
|   | TextBox4 |
+---+----------+
```

Comment: ChangePropertyAction toggling the Visibility from a Loaded EventTrigger on a parent or other object would be one way.

Comment: I looked these up on MSDN and I am somewhat confused on how to implement it. Is there anyway you can give me a quick writeup/example? Both the button and itemscontrol are both under the same grid.

Comment: Sure if I've got time no sweat, just to make sure I'm understanding correctly though (because I was a little fuzzy on that) when you say you want to create the context menu and have the options bound to the visibility, could you elaborate on that a little more? Maybe something to help visualize your overall requirements?

Comment: I added more details to the OP, let me know if there is still anything to clarify

Comment: Ok I understand a lot more now, my suggestion won't work in this instance, I was quite a bit off. I'm about to leave for the day but I'll think about it a bit more, it will require more than just XAML though like I was originally thinking.

Comment: Awesome! One thing though, are you sure its not possible to be pure XAML? Its not a requirement of mine, but the less code behind the better!

Answer (score 0):

Use a DataTemplateSelector.

This class is meant to handle the option of various data templates based on state.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx